# VS 2015: SharePoint 2013 - Empty Project, Add Module folder, "File '../scripts/app.js' was not found"

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I was created the project "**SharePoint 2013 - Empty Project**" and added module (folder) "**Scripts**" to which it enclosed the js-files, but writes that the files was not found, what's the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio is validating the open files. And reports that it can't find the script files relative to the location of your aspx file.

Close the aspx file before build.

Comment: Wow, thanks, I only recently switched to Visual studio.